# Take a screenshot in bash at a specific time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, time

So,I need to compile a code which is going to take a bunch of time to compile, at least 2-3 hours. I wanted to find a way in the bash command line, that will take a screenshoot of my screen at a specific schedule.Now,I'm going to fall asleep, and my pc has 4 hours of battery left and I'm bored to move from my bed to find my adapter which is downstairs and plug in my pc.

And If I let my pc running, it is going to be out of power before i wake up.

I've tried in my ubuntu: echo"scrot"| at thehour,
But idk why,it doesnt work.

Comment: If you need the screenshot only to find out, whether the compilation finished before the computer runs out of power, you can do achieve this simpler. Assuming that the commands to compile your application are in a shellscript `compile_all.sh`, just invoke it as `compile_all.sh; touch finished`. In the morning, if there is a file named `finished`, the compilation ran to an end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
gnome-screenshot -d 5
```

Or:

```
gnome-screenshot -d 5 -f ~/Desktop/Screenshots/filename.png
```

The `-d 5` means that the will take the screenshot in 5 seconds.

The difference between both commands is that the first will ask for you (with a GUI) to save the image in the path you want. The other it will not be necessary ask for you the path. It's saved automatically after 5 seconds.

Or you can also use the command `import -window root $HOME/Desktop/filename.png`
That will take a screenshot and will be saved in that path.
To can use the `import` command you have to install the package `image-magick`:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

After you have it installed, you can schedule the time with a bash script that executes the command `import -window root $HOME/Desktop/filename.png`. You can use sleep to can do that.
Or you can schedule the time with **KShutdown**, you will have to install it too.

```
sudo apt install kshutdown
```

Then, when you have installed the program, open it and will show something like this:

[image]

You have to select the **Extras** option and then, if you don't have scripts in the path (in my case is: `~/.local/share/kshutdown/extras`), the program will ask for you create the script.

So in that path, you will have to create a script with this content:

### #!/bin/bash

import -window root $HOME/Desktop/filename.png

or

gnome-screenshot -f ~/Desktop/Screenshots/filename.png

Now, if all is correct, the program will detect that script, and you can select it.
And to finish you will have to select the time you want the script runs.
You can select a certain time, like "23:30" or you can select **Time From Now** to run the script in certain minutes, seconds, hours...
Finally you press ok and the program will do what you want!